# How can I make pyglet start my animation from the top left instead of the bottom left?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pyglet, sprite-sheet

I followed a tutorial on how to use a sprite sheet to create an animation. It works fine and all- except for the fact that the way that my sprite sheet is set up does not work out with how pyglet runs through the sprite sheet. The way that pyglet likes to do it, is start in the bottom left, go through the row, then once it reaches the end it of that row, it goes to the left and a row above the first and so on.

I already looked around the documentation and found a comment on someone else's post saying to change the anchor_y, and when I tried that it didn't seem to change anything at all.

This is the code that creates the animation, and lower along in the program it is drawn to the screen, so that part works just fine. I wonder if there's anything I can do to change this so that I can have it cycle through my sprite sheet the way I would want it to.

```
explosion = pyglet.image.load('resources/sprites/explosion.png')
explosion_seq = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(explosion, 5, 5, item_width=32, item_height=32)
explosion_texture = pyglet.image.TextureGrid(explosion_seq)
explosion_animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(explosion_texture[0:], 0.75, loop=True)

self.explosion_sprite = Sprite(explosion_animation, x=200, y=300)
```

The way I would like it to work would be to start at the top left, cycle through the whole row, then go back to the left but then be on the row below the first one, and so on and so forth.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you supply a test-image we can try with? Would help test the code. We could create our own but lack of time it would help a lot : )

Comment: Sure! https://imgur.com/a/ZJVfalp